# How to write a dataset with HDF.PInvoke?

Tags: c#, hdf5

I'm trying to write arrays into an HDF5 file in C#, using HDF.PInvoke.

I've made a simple program that writes a 3x3 array into an HDF5 file, but when I opened it, the result is not the same as the array.

```
using HDF.PInvoke;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public unsafe partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string currentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);     
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(currentPath);                                 

            long file_id = H5F.create(@"weights.h5", H5F.ACC_TRUNC, H5P.DEFAULT, H5P.DEFAULT);

            int[,] arrInt3 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 2, 1 }, { 3, 2, 1 } };

            ulong[] dims = {3,3};

            long space_id = H5S.create_simple(2, dims, null);      

            long dataset_id = H5D.create(file_id, "/dset", H5T.STD_I32BE, space_id, H5P.DEFAULT, H5P.DEFAULT, H5P.DEFAULT);

            GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(arrInt3, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();

            long write_id = H5D.write(dataset_id, H5T.NATIVE_INT32, H5S.ALL, H5S.ALL, H5P.DEFAULT, pointer);


            long status = H5D.close(dataset_id);
            long status2 = H5S.close(space_id);
            long status3 = H5F.close(file_id);
        }
    }
}
```

When I open the file in Python, the result is

```
>>> f.root.dset
/dset (Array(1, 2)) ''
  atom := Int32Atom(shape=(), dflt=0)
  maindim := 0
  flavor := 'numpy'
  byteorder := 'big'
  chunkshape := None

>>> f.root.dset[:]
array([[0, 0]])
```

Why is it different from the original array? I'd like know where I've made mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to do this using HDF.PInvoke but, if you are not bound to this particular library, you may want to check [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) (as it greatly simplifies how to handle HDF5 files).

Writing an 3x3 array into an HDF5 file using HDFql in C# can be done as follows:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string currentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);     

    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(currentPath);    

    HDFql.Execute("CREATE TRUNCATE FILE weights.h5");

    int[,] arrInt3 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 2, 1 }, { 3, 2, 1 } };

    HDFql.Execute("CREATE DATASET weights.h5 /dset AS INT(3, 3) VALUES FROM MEMORY " + HDFql.VariableTransientRegister(arrInt3));
}
```

Please check this [webpage](http://www.hdfql.com/examples) for additional examples on how to use HDFql in C#.